# I want to insert a number by the last category number

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

My clients give me a project which some users uploads books on backend and show them on frontend with the category, reference, title etc.
The problem is the reference number must be one more number then the last reference of the book category was inserted. Maybe its confused, let me explain with an example:

Client 1, inserts a book with the category Adventure, the reference its 75 for exemple.

Client 2, inserts a book with the category Adventure, the reference must be 75 as well because its other client.

And if Client 1 inserts other book with the category Adventure the reference must be 76 because its the last number of that reference on Client 1.

Its that possible? I'm using Symfony 3
Now I have two tables, one for users and the other for books with the fields "id, name, category, reference, photo, id_client".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What i mean is, i need the numbers to increase automatically, in each client and category which is to say, i don´t want the id to increase independently from the client. So, each client can have the same number in the same category.

Answer (score 0):

First,
get the max reference value from table books where id_client=$client_id.
Second,
Insert value into table book with reference value + 1.